# Math-mode inception: creating a list environment for individually referenced equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, lists, environments, expl3

I'm trying to create a list-like environment `properties` that could be used as such:

```
\begin{properties}
  \item[Lemonade Rule] \forall \text{lemons} \exists \text{lemonade}
  \item a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \item[identity] \forall
\end{properties}
```

The idea is to redefine `\item` local to the `properties` environment such that it first ends a math environment if necessary and then starts a new one, optionally typesetting a description. (`properties` vs. `properties*` controls reference numbers, as usual.)

Unfortunately, I'm screwing up somewhere in keeping track of my modes.
I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.90   \item[inverse]
                      \label{def:group:inverse}
--- HELP ---
TeX has found either a math-mode-starting command such as \[ or \(
when it is already in math mode, or else a math-mode-ending command
such as \) or \] while in LR or paragraph mode.  The problem is caused
by either unmatched math mode delimiters or unbalanced braces.
```

Where am I messing things up?
Here is the code: **(This is new code based on the information egreg provided; it is pared down a bit in functionality from the original, but the error remains.  The old code, an apparent model of bad style, is forever available in the edit log.)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { definition } { m }
 {
  % typeset the title of the definition
  \par\noindent\hangindent\parindent
  \textbf{#1}\quad
 }
 {
   % end environment 'definition'
 }



% makes sure math content is centered
\cs_new:Nn \property_do_fill:
 {
  \hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth
 }

% enters math mode and starts a property
% does not typeset a math comment
\cs_new:Nn \property_do_begin:
 {
  \equation
  \quad\bullet
  \property_do_fill:
 }

% enters math mode and starts a property
% does typeset math comment
\cs_new:Nn \property_do_begin:n
 {
  \equation
  \quad\bullet\enspace\text{\slshape #1}
  \property_do_fill:
 }

% ends this property and exists math mode
\cs_new:Nn \property_do_end:
 {
  \property_do_fill:
  \endequation
 }


% declare a new item-like environment 'properties', where each item
% * [mathcomment]   a^2 + b^2 = c^2   (1.3)
\NewDocumentEnvironment { properties } { }
 {
   % Delimits properties
   % starts off by beginning a property, and then redefines itself
   % to end a previous property before starting a new one.
  \DeclareDocumentCommand \item { o }
   {
    \IfValueTF { ##1 }
    { \property_do_begin:n { ##1 } }
    { \property_do_begin:          }

    % redefine \item now to take care of *ending* the last one
    \DeclareDocumentCommand \item { o }
     {
      % end the last property
      \property_do_end:
      % and start a new one
      \IfValueTF { ####1 }
      { \property_do_begin:n { ####1 } }
      { \property_do_begin:            }
     }
   }
 }
 {
   % end environment properties
   % make sure to end the last property
   \property_do_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}{group}
  A group is a set $G$ together
    with a binary operation $*$ on $G$
    that satisfies the following axioms:

  \begin{properties}
  \item[associativity]
    \label{def:group:assoc}
    \forall{a,b,c \in G}{(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)}
  \item[identity]
    \label{def:group:identity}
    \exists e \in G : \forall{a \in G}{a * e = a = e * a}
  \item[inverse]
    \label{def:group:inverse}
    \forall{x \in G}{\exists b \in G : a * b = b * a = e}
  \end{properties}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\equation*` is *two* tokens, not one; and you can't abbreviate `\begin{equation*}` into `\equation*`. You can't test `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` in a `\cs_new:Nn` instruction; that's reserved to `\NewDocumentCommand` (and the alike commands). While you can do `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{s}`, the relative `\IfBooleanTF` will be true when you call `\begin{foo}*`, not `\begin{foo*}` (which is undefined).

Comment: @egreg — so general misunderstandings all around? I'll see if I can fix it up myself given this information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid your code is wrong in so many respects that almost nothing can be salvaged.

### First error

```
\cs_new:Nn \property_do_begin:n
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 } \equation* \equation
  \quad\bullet
  \property_do_fill:
 }
```

The `\IfBooleanTF` function makes sense only in the body of `\NewDocumentCommand` (or alike functions), because it's this function that sets up things so that a `*` will set the internal boolean to true or false. In `\cs_new:Nn` the result is basically unpredictable. See the third error for other problems; actually this *might* work in some cases, because the argument is passed from an "interface" command; but it's considered "bad style" anyway.

### Second error

Even if `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` were successful (which may not), when you use it in

```
\IfBooleanTF { #1 } \endequation* \endequation
```

you'd get `\equation` if a `*` follows and a `*` otherwise; in both cases the second `\equation` would be executed. This is because `\equation*` is *two* tokens and you can't abbreviate `\begin{equation*}` with `\equation*`. The same for `\endequation*`, of course.

### Third error

With `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{<arg specs>}{<start>}{<end>}` you're basically doing

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{<arg specs>}{<start>}{<end>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\endfoo}{<arg specs>}{<start>}{<end>}
```

and the arguments passed to `\foo` after `\begin{foo}` will be passed also to `\endfoo` when called by `\end{foo}`.

Thus `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{s}` would define only the `foo` environment, not the `foo*` environment. When you call

```
\begin{foo}
```

your `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` will evaluate to false. And `\begin{foo*}` will raise an error. You could call `\begin{foo}*`, however, and `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` would evaluate to true.

Comment: Most of this was stemming from my blatant oversight of `\begin{env*}` vs. `\begin{env}*`; I've made (what I thought to be) the necessary modifications to my code and simplified it significantly—but to no effect (the same error).  Should I edit my question to reflect the new code, or should I ask a new one?